# Ao enviar Formulario o Anexo está vindo null. ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Ao enviar o formulário, tudo no controller chega preenchido, menos o arquivo que é anexado. Onde está o erro?

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult EnviaEmail(string destinatario, string assunto, string mensagem, FileStream arquivo)
            {
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                client.Port = 28;
                client.Host = "exchange.minhaempresa.local";
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Timeout = 10000;
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("gustavo.r", "123456");

                MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("gustavo.r@email.com.br", destinatario, assunto, mensagem);
                mm.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
                mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;

                mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(arquivo, "attachment"));
                //mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fileAttachment));

                client.Send(mm);

                return View();
            }
```

html:

```
 <form id="formulario" action="~/Gerenciamento/EnvioEmail/EnviaEmail" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>Destinatario:</label><input type="text" name="destinatario" /><br />
        <label>Assunto:</label><input type="text" name="assunto" /><br />
        <label>Mensagem:</label> <textarea name="mensagem" /></textarea><br />
        <label>Anexo:</label><input name="arquivo" type="file" />
        <button>Enviar</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Nunca fiz upload usando a classe `FileStream`, já tentou usar `HttpPostedFileBase`?

Comment: é que  mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(arquivo, "attachment")) espera uma string. Como ficaria?

Comment: A classe `HttpPosteFileBase` tem o método `InputStream` para resolver isso :)
Pode ser asssim: `mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(arquivo.InputStream, "attachment")) `

Comment: deu certo. Coloque na resposta que eu marco. Outra coisa... Tem com eu pegar   um array de arquivos? tipo como ficaria pra pecorrer os anexo? ex:HttpPostedFileBase[] fileUploader

Comment: Sim é isso mesmo para multiplos arquivos, use um List no lugar o array, coloquei na resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitua a classe `FileStream` por `HttpPostedFileBase`:

```
public ActionResult EnviaEmail(string destinatario, string assunto, string mensagem, FileStream arquivo)
```

Para ler o *Stream*, use o método `InputStream`:

```
mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(arquivo.InputStream, "attachment"))
```

Sobre múltiplos arquivos, basta alterar o html para permitir selecionar multiplos arquivos:

```
<input name="arquivo" type="file" multiple="multiple"/>
```

Na *Action*, agora receber um **List**:

```
List<HttpPostedFileBase> arquivos
```

E depois um `foreach` para cada arquivo postado:

```
foreach (HttpPostedFileBase postedFile in arquivos)
{
  ....
}
```

Comment: Obrigada, vou postar a resposta completa de como ficou

Answer (score 1):

Segue a resposta completa funcionando, com base na sugestão do @Ricardo Pontual

```
 public ActionResult EnviaEmail(string destinatario, string assunto, string mensagem, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> fileUploader)// string fileAttachment)
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Port = 25;
            client.Host = "exchange.minhaempresa.local";
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Timeout = 40000;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("gustavo.r", "123456");

            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("gustavo.r@email.com.br", destinatario, assunto, mensagem);
            mm.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
            mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;

            // string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileUploader.FileName);
            // mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fileUploader.InputStream, fileName));

            string fileName = "";
            if (fileUploader != null)

            {

                foreach (var file in fileUploader)
                {
                       fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                        mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(file.InputStream, fileName));

                }

            }



            client.Send(mm);

            return View();
        }
```

html:

```
  <form id="formulario" action="~/Gerenciamento/EnvioEmail/EnviaEmail" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>Destinatario:</label><input type="text" name="destinatario" /><br />
        <label>Assunto:</label><input type="text" name="assunto" /><br />
        <label>Mensagem:</label> <textarea name="mensagem" /></textarea><br />
        <label>Anexo:</label><input name="fileUploader" type="file" multiple />
        <button>Enviar</button>
    </form>
```